# CSS - changing font color in a sidebar

Tags: css, fonts, colors

http://ratest3.com/news/

I'm trying to change the text the the left hand sidebar area.  Everything in the div #primary (to #fff).

I have tried (along with a few other things);

```
#primary .widget-area {color: #fff;}
```

and it still wants to obey the line on 201 of style.css

Comment: What is the rule in use on line 201? It's possibly too specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!important`:

```
#primary .widget-area {color: #fff!important;}
```

**Edit**:

It's

```
#primary.widget-area {color: #fff!important;}
```

(without space) because

- `#primary .widget-area` means all elements with class `widget-area` inside the element with id `primary`.
- `#primary.widget-area` means the element with id `primary` which has also the class `widget-area`.

Comment: Yes, you can use `!important`, but it shouldn't be the first solution to try. It's possible that the rule that takes priority is written in a way that makes it too specific and it just needs to be re-written.

Comment: The important wasn't neessary... it is the 'without space'.  :)  Danke!

Comment: @stevelove He said he tried many things and he hadn't post his webpage yet so I couldn't see what was happening, so I thought that the best way would be using `important!`. But you are right, if it is possible its use should be avoided.

@KBarnes Bitte schön!